# What is the difference between asp and asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, asp-classic, asp.net-2.0

I'm wondering what is the difference between asp and asp.net?

Comment: there is a big difference like the answers below illustrate. However these days most people just use the term ASP or just .NET when they refer to ASP.NET because that it's just assumed that is what most ppl are using

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ASP.NET is not the same as ASP. The "old" ASP is now called classic ASP.
ASP.NET is a [Markup Language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markup_language) can, among other things, use the server server controls to run elements.

As for example:

```
<form id="MyForm" runat="server">
```

Then you said that it will run on the server and you have an id to control it.

- NET is the framework (such as a
  library)
- C #, J #, VB.NET, they are the main
  [script languages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scripting_language) for communicating with.
  NET
- ASP.NET is [Markup Language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markup_language) . 
  it runs on the server side. It generates xml / html / xHTML even further, to the user. In many ways one can compare ASP.NET, with WinForms. Then there is a way to visually show something to the user.

Answer (score 0):

There is several differences between `asp`(sometimes called `classic asp`) and `asp.net`

1. ASP is interpreted while ASP.NET is compiled, That's why ASP.NET work faster then ASP.
2. ASP use ADO while ASP.NET use ADO.NET to for database connectivity.
3. ASP usage classic languages like VB Script while ASP.NET use .NET classes like C#.
4. ASP page use .asp extension and ASP.NET use .aspx extensions.